# FFMPEG: How to fix WebM file which was created by stitching multiple WebM files?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libvpx

I have a file that has multiple `WebM(vp9/opus)` streams stitched together sequentially.

When trying to play it through regular media players it stops at the end of 1st stream in the sequence.

When used with `FFMPEG` for transcoding it to `MP4`, the trancoding stops at the end of first stream.

Using `FFMPEG` is it possible to make a regular `WebM(vp9/opus)` file from a file that contains multiple `WebM(vp9/opus)` stitched together sequentially?

Comment: You could try to use `-ss`and `-t`to select a specific part of your video corresponding to a single stream.
[Documentation for main options including -t and -ss](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Main-options)
[An example in another question](https://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and suggestion! I could try that, but the end goal i'm trying to achieve is to process a stream of data of the nature explained in the question above, so the solution i was looking out for is to tweak the trancoder to accommodate the varying nature of the stream.

Comment: I assume you don't have the original WebMs anymore. Are you working with a file or data stream i.e. is the input seekable and persistent?

Comment: @Gyan i do have file containing the multiple streams stitched together for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with **ffmpeg** command line, but if you are writing your own transcoder based on ffmpeg libraries (`avformat` and `avcodec`), you can use a custom AVIOContext; when the first stream is finished, your context handler will know the file offset; now, you can skip forward until you come across the next `1a 45 df a3` marker, and open the next 'input file' at this position.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! If you have any pointers towards a sample implementation for referring to it would be great!

Comment: I would start with the official [transcode](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcoding.c) example. [Here](https://github.com/alexcohn/mobile-ffmpeg/commit/0c8aaa72cbf7684598e50d92f929a437b326542c) you can see how a custom AVIOContext can be introduced. *You don't need the fd-specific logic there, but I would suggest to do all your work with **stdin**, then you don't care which input file to open*.